# Может ли соотечественник быть "своим", или это тавтология?

Tags: тавтология

Может ли соотечественник быть "своим", или это тавтология?

> У меня предложение: нужно любить не только Родину, но и (своих)
> соотечественников, которые...

Нужно ли здесь слово "своих", или соотечественник и так свой?